# Http Get response

Tags: http, get

I created a http client in C. I want to get just the data sent by server. The data is normally after the empty line (\r\n\r\n). The problem is when I try GET on a html page after the empty line I get a number then the line \n0.

I don't know the signification of these two numbers.

When I try GET on a image file I don't get theses two numbers.

Someone can explain me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does the response have "Transfer-Encoding: chunked" header?

If so, the response is chunked encoded and the numbers may be chunk-size and last-chunk. The response is split into many chunks and the each chunk-size tells size of each chunk and the last-chunk must be "0\r\n" by [HTTP/1.1 specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-3.6.1).